# Sakai: How do I get a site (course) listing with REST or WS interface?

Tags: rest, sakai

I am trying to interface with Sakai from an external application in order to get read only course information (identifier, course name, description, instructor, etc.). It looks (/direct/site/describe) like the "site" REST service only expose things that need you to have the course ID already. I noticed while browsing the Sakai source there is a SiteService that has a method called getSites() which looks a lot like what I need but (disclaimer) I know almost nothing about Sakai. I just need this data.

My question is: This seems like something that should be there am I missing something? Also, is the best way forward just to expose the SiteService getSites through a custom service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to just get a listing of every site in a Sakai installation then you will have to build something custom since the complete listing of all sites is not a typical use case. Generally applications are more interested in getting the listing of sites which a specific user has access to. For example:

```
http://nightly2.sakaiproject.org:8081/direct/site.json
```

Will return the complete listing (possibly with paging) for the currently logged in user.

```
{"entityPrefix": "site", "site_collection": [
{
  "createdDate": 1401938965607,
  "createdTime": {
    "display": "Jun 4, 2014 11:29 pm",
    "time": 1401938965607
  },
  "description": null,
  "htmlDescription": "",
  "htmlShortDescription": "",
  "iconUrl": null,
  "iconUrlFull": null,
  "id": "61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9",
  "infoUrl": null,
  "infoUrlFull": null,
  "joinerRole": null,
  "lastModified": 1401938965993,
  "maintainRole": "maintain",
  "modifiedDate": 1401938965993,
  "modifiedTime": {
    "display": "Jun 4, 2014 11:29 pm",
    "time": 1401938965993
  },
  "owner": "admin",
  "props": {
    "contact-name": "Sakai Administrator"
  },
  "providerGroupId": null,
  "reference": "\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9",
  "shortDescription": null,
  "siteGroups": null,
  "siteOwner": {
    "userDisplayName": "Sakai Administrator",
    "userEntityURL": "\/direct\/user\/admin",
    "userId": "admin"
  },
  "sitePages": [
    {
      "id": "e051601e-2162-47c1-9e04-63a033f56cdf",
      "layout": 0,
      "layoutTitle": "Single Column Layout",
      "position": 0,
      "props": {
        "is_home_page": "true"
      },
      "reference": "\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9\/page\/e051601e-2162-47c1-9e04-63a033f56cdf",
      "siteId": "61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9",
      "skin": "neo-default",
      "title": "Home",
      "titleCustom": false,
      "url": "http:\/\/nightly2.sakaiproject.org:8081\/portal\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9\/page\/e051601e-2162-47c1-9e04-63a033f56cdf",
      "activeEdit": false,
      "popUp": false
    },
    {
      "id": "2e7c2004-0dc2-47bc-8e55-ca1df8e58c33",
      "layout": 0,
      "layoutTitle": "Single Column Layout",
      "position": 1,
      "props": null,
      "reference": "\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9\/page\/2e7c2004-0dc2-47bc-8e55-ca1df8e58c33",
      "siteId": "61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9",
      "skin": "neo-default",
      "title": "Assignments",
      "titleCustom": false,
      "url": "http:\/\/nightly2.sakaiproject.org:8081\/portal\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9\/page\/2e7c2004-0dc2-47bc-8e55-ca1df8e58c33",
      "activeEdit": false,
      "popUp": false
    },
    {
      "id": "332c52a8-89fe-45bb-9b1a-bf6bace3e88a",
      "layout": 0,
      "layoutTitle": "Single Column Layout",
      "position": 2,
      "props": null,
      "reference": "\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9\/page\/332c52a8-89fe-45bb-9b1a-bf6bace3e88a",
      "siteId": "61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9",
      "skin": "neo-default",
      "title": "Site Info",
      "titleCustom": false,
      "url": "http:\/\/nightly2.sakaiproject.org:8081\/portal\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9\/page\/332c52a8-89fe-45bb-9b1a-bf6bace3e88a",
      "activeEdit": false,
      "popUp": false
    }
  ],
  "skin": null,
  "softlyDeletedDate": null,
  "title": "AZ",
  "type": "project",
  "userRoles": [
    "maintain",
    "access"
  ],
  "activeEdit": false,
  "customPageOrdered": false,
  "empty": false,
  "joinable": false,
  "pubView": true,
  "published": true,
  "softlyDeleted": false,
  "entityReference": "\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9",
  "entityURL": "http:\/\/nightly2.sakaiproject.org:8081\/direct\/site\/61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9",
  "entityId": "61a1ebbd-e507-4ca3-8f88-65abca0803d9",
  "entityTitle": "AZ"
},{
...
```

Since you have a very specific use case, I would suggest you use the SiteService (or possibly even SQL) to retrieve the very limited data you are looking for and then add a new custom method to the SiteEntityProvider (https://source.sakaiproject.org/svn/entitybroker/trunk/core-providers/src/java/org/sakaiproject/entitybroker/providers/SiteEntityProvider.java) like so:

```
@EntityCustomAction(action = "my_custom_method", viewKey = EntityView.VIEW_SHOW)
public boolean myCustomMethod(EntityView view) {
    HashMap yourMap = new HashMap();
    // put code here to get all the sites data you need from the SiteService or the DB and then put the parts you want to return into a Map and then return that map
    return yourMap;
}
```

You could then call that method like so:

```
http://nightly2.sakaiproject.org:8081/direct/site/my_custom_method.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try using JWS to get some information.

There is some default service in sakai (ROOT_OF_TOMCAT\webapps\sakai-axis), which you can access via: http://xxx.xxx/sakai-axis/xxx.jws?wsdl ).

The serivce *"SakaiLogin.jws"* helps you log into sakai:

```java
public String login(String id,String pw) throws AxisFault
```

The service *"SakaiScript.jws"* provides a function called:

```java
public String getAllSitesForUser(String sessionid) throws AxisFault
```

which can return a list of all sites associated with this user.

Maybe I am not answering your question correctly (since I am using SOAP). I hope this could be of some help to you.

I am also writing a program to retrieve data from sakai too. But I don't quite understand how to expose data via REST or Entity Broker.

Cheers.

---

**Update:**

You can try `wsdl2java.bat` brought with Apache Axis2. It will generate a Java Class from a WSDL service. Then you can use it directly to consume these services provided in Sakai. Like:

```
wsdl2java.bat -p org.sakai.wsdl -uri http://localhost:8080/sakai-axis/Assignments.jws?wsdl
```

I am already using it and feel it really convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Yes the SakaiScript web service endpoint is pretty useful but did not serve the purposes we needed. Like you said, getAllSitesForUser seems interesting we need a list of sites to present for registration, not after they have been associated. We could have a user that is registered with all sites, but at that point it's starting to feel wrong-ish.

Answer (score 0):

All Sakai sites can be listed using the `getAllSitesCollectionSize` method in Sakai's `contenthostingservice`.  It ought to be called `getAllSites`. Don't ask me why it was named like that!

See, for instance, https://qa11-mysql.nightly.sakaiproject.org/sakai-ws .